# hi! I want to loop over this list

Tags: python, loops, for-loop, indexing, while-loop

I want to loop over this list one item at a time, I want to have 0th element as constant and for every 0th element I want to have 1st,2nd,..... till last element and then repeat the process I.e for 1st element I want to have 2nd,3rd,4th.... last element and so on. I have tried for loop and while loop, but due to index error in the first cycle it is not going to the second cycle. Kindly guide. Thankyou in advance.

--

```
type here
ls = ['aa','bb','cc','dd','ee','ff','gg','hh']

for i in range(len(ls)):
    print("this is first loop", i)
    j=i
    while j <= len(ls):
        print("this is second loop", j+1)
        print("this is second loop", ls[j+1])
        j+=1
```

```
    this is first loop 0
    this is second loop 1
    this is second loop bb
    this is second loop 2
    this is second loop cc
    this is second loop 3
    this is second loop dd
    this is second loop 4
    this is second loop ee
    this is second loop 5
    this is second loop ff
    this is second loop 6
    this is second loop gg
    this is second loop 7
    this is second loop hh
    this is second loop 8
    Traceback (most recent call last):
    print("this is second loop", ls[j+1])
    IndexError: list index out of range
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  The reason for your issue is you increment ```j```  and when ```j = len(ls)```, your ```ls[j + 1]``` will be greater than the length of the list.

Comment: just do `ls[j]` instead of `ls[j+1]` so you don't get an index error (add one to `j` before the second loop if you want).

Comment: `itertools` has functions for doing `product`, `permutations`, etc; probably don't reinvent the wheel.

Comment: Question was closed as I was posting my answer.  Consider using `enumerate()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a second for-loop like this:

```
ls = ['aa','bb','cc','dd','ee','ff','gg','hh']

for i in range(len(ls)):
    print("this is first loop", i)
    for j in range(i + 1, len(ls)):
        print("this is second loop", j)
        print("this is second loop", ls[j])
```